# How to Properly Use Vue Router beforeRouteEnter or Watch to trigger method in Single File Component?

Tags: vue.js, components, watch, vue-router

I'm working on an app in Vue.js using Single File Components and Vue Router. I have a Search component where I need to execute a method to re-populate search results each time a user visits the route. The method executes correctly the first time the route is visited because of the "create" hook:

```
created: function() {
    this.initializeSearch();
  },
```

However, when the user leaves the route (to register or log into the app for instance), and returns to the Search page, I can't seem to find a way to automatically trigger this.initializeSearch() on subsequent visits.

Routes are set up in index.js like so:

```
import Search from './components/Search.vue';
import Login from './components/Login.vue';
import Register from './components/Register.vue';

// Vue Router Setup
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Search },
  { path: '/register', component: Register },
  { path: '/login', component: Login },
  { path: '*', redirect: '/' }
]

export const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})
```

I gather that I should be using "watch" or "beforeRouteEnter" but I can't seem to get either to work.

I tried using "watch" like so within my Search component:

```
watch: {
    // Call the method again if the route changes
    '$route': 'initializeSearch'
  }
```

And I can't seem to find any documentation explaining how to properly use the beforeRouteEnter callback with a single file component (the vue-router documentation isn't very clear).

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you caching your routes using <keep-alive> for your <router-view>

Answer (score 21):

Since you want to re-populate search results each time a user visits the route.

You can use `beforeRouteEnter()` in your component as below:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) { 
  next(vm => { 
    // access to component's instance using `vm` .
    // this is done because this navigation guard is called before the component is created.            
    // clear your previously populated search results.            
    // re-populate search results
    vm.initializeSearch();
  }) 
}
```

You can read more about navigation guards [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lydf8ygL/2/)

Comment: @hipertracker added an example to my answer. Have a look.

Comment: How would one accomplish this inside a TypeScript class? I currently do `@Component({ beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) { this.beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next); } }`, but that's not very clean, right?

Comment: may I know how if we want to go specific router after evaluating `vm.checkPolicy()` for example, inside the `next` callback?

Comment: Dead link for navigation guards. [Vue Router V4 Link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)